# Change dll attributes(product Name) of third party references

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a use case where I want to update the "Product Name" of all my dlls
[Like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQwvY.png)

I tried using the approach discussed in:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows
as a post build step
or I opened them in Visual Studio and added the product name wherever possible.

This worked well for most dlls. But I have some dlls(like NewtonSoft.Json.Dll) which are packaged as references. When I edit the *product* name of these dlls they just stop loading. I dont want to open them in Visual Studio either as it is part of build process by Visual Studio where it will put packages in the bin directory. It feels something is getting corrupted when I am trying to change their attributes.

How do I fix this?

Is it somehow possible to edit the nuget package file to change this information?

Comment: I am changing the product name. In my guess it should not have to do anything with what that dll is referencing.

Comment: This seems strange why do you want to do this? and yes its likely to cause problems for various reasons

Comment: I want to do this as a post build step. What reasons would it cause problems?